# How Do I Collapse The Margins on my Responsive Site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So if you go to this URL:

http://azletconsulting.com/issues/

You'll see the the centered text div with lorem ipsum in it. When I decrease browser width though, you'll see the right margin only collapses pushing the edge of the text div in on the right side. What CSS code am I missing so that the outside margins of the DIV collapse equally keeping the text div centered instead of just crushing the right side in? This goes for pretty much every DIV on the site though, the text ones are just the most noticeable.

Thanks 
Baroti

Comment: basically this is what I'm looking to occur when browser width changes, I just can't figured out what is breaking it in my current CSS code.
http://jsfiddle.net/LHCbk/

Comment: I actually think the issue is more with the buttons below the text. The text div now keeps it's margins after displaying it as a block, with margin: 0 auto; but the buttons refuse to adjust themselves to keep themselves aligned under the text div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have written margin-left in % in ".issues_nav" which is pushing the elements.
If you want to center the element its better to use.

`margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:block`

Comment: I changed this on my local build and it still just collapses the right margin pushing in the right side of the text div unequally compared to the left. I just want both the left & right side of the div to collapse equally, whiling maintaining the 80% aspect ratio until it hits the next media query.